# how to use filling in Graphic plots

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, color, filling

i'm going to plot some angles in Trigonometric circle by using Graphic command
how can i use filling axes by different colors in this program or color between the angles?

```
angles[t_] := Module[{o = {0, 0}, p = {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, rot},
   rot = If[TrueQ[Pi/2 < Mod[t, 2 Pi] < 3 Pi/2], t + Pi, t];
   {{Opacity[0.3], Line[{o, p}]}, 
    Rotate[Inset[Style[Row[{t}], FontSize -> 18], p/2], rot]}];
Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Blue, 
  Table[angles[
    t  Degree ], {t  , {52, 0, 220, 180, 132, 282, 90, 320}}]}, 
 Axes -> True, Ticks -> None]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Filling` is not an option for `Graphics`, One approach is to use a `PieChart` as a background.

```
angles[t_] := 
  Module[{o = {0, 0}, p = {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, rot}, 
   rot = If[TrueQ[Pi/2 < Mod[t, 2 Pi] < 3 Pi/2], t + Pi, t];
   {{Opacity[0.3], Line[{o, p}]}, 
    Rotate[Inset[Style[Row[{t}], FontSize -> 18], p/2], rot]}];

ang = {52, 0, 220, 180, 132, 282, 90, 320} Degree // Sort;

ang = Append[ang, First[ang] + 360 Degree];

Show[
 PieChart[Differences@ang/(360 Degree), 
  SectorOrigin -> {0, "Counterclockwise"}, 
  ColorFunction -> ({Opacity[0.65], 
      ColorData["TemperatureMap"][RandomReal[]]} &),
  ColorFunctionScaling -> True],
 Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Blue, 
   Table[angles[t Degree], {t, {52, 0, 220, 180, 132, 282, 90, 320}}]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think using circular sectors generated with `Disk` may be easier:

```
SeedRandom[3]

Clear[sector, angles]
sector[color_, angle_List] := {color, Disk[{0, 0}, .995, {angle[[1]], angle[[2]]} Degree]}

angles[t_] := Module[
  {o = {0, 0}, p = {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, rot},
  rot = If[TrueQ[Pi/2 < Mod[t, 2 Pi] < 3 Pi/2], t + Pi, t];
  {{Opacity[0.3], Line[{o, p}]}, Rotate[Inset[Style[Row[{t}], FontSize -> 18], p/2], rot]}
  ]

listofangles = Sort@{52, 0, 220, 180, 132, 282, 90, 320};
listofcolors = RandomReal[1, Length[listofangles]];


Graphics[{
  (* The outer circle *)
  Thick, Red, Circle[],

  (* Circular sectors generated from listofangles, colored by listofcolors*)
  MapThread[
   sector[Hue[#1], #2] &,
   {listofcolors, Append[Partition[listofangles, 2, 1], {listofangles[[-1]], 360}]}
   ],

  (* Angles values and separating lines, from OP's code *)
  {Darker@Blue, Table[angles[t Degree], {t, listofangles}]}
}]
```

[image: Colored disk]

---

I used a list of randomly chosen colors here. However, you can **specify colors of your choosing** by assigning a list of color names to `listofcolors`. You need to specify as many colors as you have angles in `listofangles`.